# how to get different between specific time of 2 days in hours using mysql or php

Tags: mysql

i just need to get the different between specific time of 2 days in hours. so kindly let me know what is the possibility of it by using mysql.

```
T1= 2017-04-25 14:05:20
T2= 2017-04-28 17:20:10
```

so how can i get the value of `T3 (T3=T2-T1)` in hours using MySQL. If it is cant is there any possibility to use php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[TIMESTAMPDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function of MySQL will helps you.

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2017-04-25 14:05:20', '2017-04-28 17:20:10');
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: thank you simply modified the answer 
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2017-04-28 14:20:20', '2017-05-28 17:19:30')/60;